# Boot linux bootloader from Mac OSX

Tags: linux, fedora, osx, grub2, uefi

I was running Fedora 17 on my computer which was an HP windows based machine. Unfortunately my computer has a malfunctioning motherboard and will no longer turn on. I removed the hard drive and using a hard drive enclosure I plugged into my backup machine ( Macbook Pro ) hoping I could boot the hard drive from it. Unfortunately the Mac's EFI does not recognize the hard drive as bootable. Is there a way I can boot my hard drive which contains a Fedora 17 partition with Grub 2 as the bootloader and a few other linux distros from my MacBook Pro ?